# Ghidra: equivalent to IDA-Pro's "Reset desktop"

Tags: ghidra

I have nearly ruined my Ghidra layout, and was wondering if there is an equivalent to IDA-Pro's Windows->Reset Desktop, which would reset the code browser's layout to its default form.

I am aware that I can drag the floating windows back into position.

Comment: when i have too many windows open i simply close all except for program tree , decompiler, and listing iirc the other windows simply expand to fill the space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of is to reimport the tool. Specifically:

1. From the Ghidra Project window, right click on the code browser tool and click `Delete...`
2. `Tools -> Import Default Tools...`
3. Select `defaultsTools/CodeBrowser.tool`, then `OK`

Worth noting, while in your case it makes sense to delete the current (i.e. broken) tool, that's not a strict requirement. If you import the default tool with a `CodeBrowser` tool already there, it'll just be imported as `CodeBrowser_1` and leave the original tool as-is.

Answer (score -2):

In the project view, open Edit -> Tool Options. Select the "Tool" section, and change the "Swing Look and Feel" to whatever you like. I chose GTK+. Restart Ghidra and you should be back in action.